# Cómo se define un color a partir del range en un scale lineal

Tags: javascript, d3.js

No entiendo bien cómo se define un color a partir de lo del range. se le pasan 5 colores en rgb, cómo se sabe que color se le asigna?

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr({width:w, height:h});

var color = d3.scale.linear()
                .range(['rgb(254,240,217)', 'rgb(253,212,158)', 'rgb(253,187,132)', 'rgb(254,141,89)' ])

d3.csv("state-sales.csv", function(data) {
    color.domain([
        0, d3.max(data, function(d) {return d.sales;})
    ])
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Ese fragmento de código lo que hace es establecer una relación lineal entre los colores y las ventas utilizando una escala. La escala lo que hace es transformar un numero en cierto intervalo (llamado el dominio) en otro numero en otro intervalo (llamado el rango). El rango y el dominio, no necesitan ser números, mientras se puedan convertir en números, es posible trabajar con ellos.

En este caso el rango se define con `.range()` y corresponde a los colores posibles.

Con `.domain()` se definen los datos que puedes ingresar a la función, en este caso de 0 hasta la máxima venta (Con `d3.max` se obtuvo la máxima venta).

Comment: Si amigo, muy amable por responder, pero no entiendo lo del array de colores, como sabe d3.js que color poner? es decir hay 5 colores, cómo sabe cual poner?